# Error message: "Property 'EyeDropper' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'."

Tags: typescript, vue.js, window

I want to use "window.EyeDropper" in a (vue2 + ts) project. When I write this line of code:

```
console.log(window.EyeDropper);
```

My plugins Vetur throws an error message:Property 'EyeDropper' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.

How can I modify the code to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and/or add to `src/globals.d.ts`:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    EyeDropper?: any;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)
But I still have some questions, whether can you help me?
When I code `new EyeDropper()`, I receive a new error message"Cannot find name 'EyeDropper'. Did you mean 'eyeDropper'? -Vetur". Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: This is Document from MDN with EyeDroppper: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EyeDropper

Comment: Might be related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/76669995/10939108