# When I use EyeDropper API throw error 'EyeDropper' is not defined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, google-chrome, window

I need to use EyeDropper to complete a eyedropper.
My project use Vue2 + Ts, my code:

```
<div
  v-if="haveEyeDropper"
  @click="handleClickPick"
>
  <i class="iconfont icon-xiguan"></i>
</div>

handleClickPick(): void {
  const eyeDropper = new EyeDropper();
  // ...
}
```

I receive Errors "Cannot find name 'EyeDropper'. Did you mean 'eyeDropper'? -Vetur" and "'EyeDropper' is not defined -eslint"
But I copy MDN-document(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EyeDropper) example code in a `index.html`, it works.

(My Browser is Chrome edition 105.0.5195.52)

Answer (score 2):

Can you check is your application running on [Secure Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)? *(Most likely within local development)*

```js
window.isSecureContext
```

If it is not running in secure context you can not access EyeDropper API (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EyeDropper)):

[image]

If thats the case; you may choose to access your application over HTTPS by using ngnix etc.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a feasible plan, but it is not very standard.

I added the following code to index.html:

```
<script>
  if (!!window.EyeDropper) {
    window.EyeDropperTarget = new EyeDropper();
  }
</script>
```

I check window.EyeDropper, if have it, I mount `new EyeDropper()` example on `window`.

Then I can use it in business code:

```
handleClickPick(): void {
  const picker = window.EyeDropperTarget;

  picker.open().then((result: any) => {
    const color = result?.sRGBHex;
    // ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My leader gave me a standard method with the folloing code：

```
new example = (window as any).EyeDropper()
```

Vetur reports the error because: Esline unrecognized window new Api.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that variable/type on Window.
Like any new variable (not default) on the "window" object.

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        EyeDropper?: any;
    }
}
```

Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709880/4978626